# Matlab. Image processing on 8 ball pool flash game. Small cheat. Hehe

Tags: matlab, image-processing

See the picture below. It's a flash game from a well known website :)

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/837/poolu.jpg/

I'd like to capture the images, frame by frame, using Matlab, and then lenghten the line that goes from the 8 ball, the short one, so i can see exactly where it will go. And display another window, in which the exact pool table will appear but with longer lines for the paths :)

I know, or can easily find out, how to capture the screen and whatnot, the problem is that i'm not sure how to start detecting those lines, to see the direction they are heading towards. Can anyone suggest an idea on how to accomplish this? Any image processing techniques i could use to at least filter out everything except those lines. 
Not sure where to even start looking, or for WHAT.

And yeah, it's a cheat i know. But i got programming skills, why not put them in practice? :D Help me out people, it's a fun project :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try using the [Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) in the [Matlab Image Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/hough.html).

EDIT1:
Basically the Hough transform is a technique for detecting linear structures (lines) in an image.